# Confusing index notation in cosmological perturbation theory

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, notation, cosmological-inflation

On page 24 of the report 'Inflation and Cosmological Perturbation Theory' by S. Auddy (available [here](https://physics.iitm.ac.in/%7Esriram/professional/mentoring/p-reports/sayantan.pdf)), the concept of a perturbed metric tensor is discussed. In this text, a vector is decomposed as $g_{0i}^{(1)} = \partial_i B + Q_i$, where $B$ is a scalar and $Q_i$ represents a vector. This vector is said to be divergence free, and the author writes this as $\partial_i Q^i = 0$. My question is simply this: why have we now found it necessary to raise the index on $Q$? Why is the condition not written as $\partial_i Q_i$?

Perhaps my confusion lies in the fact that the components of a vector are often written with raised indices, but the basis vectors have lowered indices. This doesn't seem to be the case in the construction of $g_{0i}^{(1)}$ though, even though the same paper uses terms like $dx^i$ and $dx^j$ in the construction of the metric. What am I missing?

Comment: This isn't an answer since I haven't read the reference and don't know the context, but (a) this is a master's thesis; if your goal is to learn cosmological perturbation theory you may want to consult more authoritative sources like [Mukhanov, Feldman, and Brandenberger](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037015739290044Z), (b) since $Q^i=g^{ij}Q_j$ and for the FLRW metric with zero spatial curvature and in "usual" coordinates $g^{ij}=a^{-2}(t)\delta^{ij}$, there is a difference between the numerical values of $Q^i$ and $Q_i$.

Comment: Also in physics we are almost always talking about components of tensors, rather than the tensors themselves. It is very common in physics to use the word "vector" to refer to the components of a vector $A^\mu$ rather than the basis vectors $\mathbf{v}_\mu$.